# Animate Train in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to animate a 20 wagon train in iphone. The train will move left to right. Each wagon will have a different animation. I was confused how to do it. Because the images are large and 20 images at one time would cause memory warnings.

Can anyone suggest how to go about it. Should I use cocos2d for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that in cocos2d.

I would create a 'Wagon'-class and then start by initiate two of them (just because I think that two wagons will fill the screen). And then start moving the wagons. Each time a wagon is completely out of the screen I would release it. When it's time for the next wagon I would initiate that and so on.

How many frames does the animations have, and how big are they? Maybe you'll have to make one atlas per wagon. You can always call:

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
```

and:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the clue I was looking for. I have not yet made the frames. But it would have minimum 10-15 frames.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D is best!

Create sprites, set actions to it and IMHO!!!

If you want to do using UIImageViews, look for

```
UIImageView.animationImages
UIImageView.animationDuration
UIImageView.animationRepeatCount
```

and

```
[UIView beginAnimations:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration]

// make the changes in your view which you want to occur in given duration

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But again, this will definitely give you a hard time, better go for Cocos2D.

Comment: Well if each wagon of train is 300*200 in width and has 10 frames then total frames is 10*20=200 frames. Can I do this with Cocos2d.

Comment: in Cocos2D the canvas size is limited to 1024x1024, so I think you will need to manipulate the sprites, or you can try to shrink the size of train wagon, but yes can be done in Cocos2d